# How to route requests to a dynamic endpoint on kong api-gateway

Tags: api-gateway, kong, kong-plugin

I have a service named alpha (created using python-django) that runs on `http://127.0.0.1:9000` and has these two endpoings

- `/health` returns `{"health": "OK"} status 200`
- `/codes/<str:code>` returns `{"code": code} status 200`

I also have a kong api-gateway in the db-less declarative mode that runs on localhost port 80

in kong.yaml I have two services

```
services:
  - name: local-alpha-health
    url: http://host.docker.internal:9000/health
    routes:
      - name: local-alpha-health
        methods:
          - GET
        paths:
          - /alpha/health
        strip_path: true
  - name: local-alpha-code
    url: http://host.docker.internal:9000/code/ # HOW TO WRITE THIS PART???
    routes:
      - name: local-alpha-code
        methods:
          - GET
        paths:
          - /alpha/code/(?<appcode>\d+) # Is this right???
        strip_path: true
```

- If I send a `GET` request to `http://127.0.0.1/alpha/health` it returns `{"health": "OK"} status 200` which shows kong is working.
- I want to send a request such as `http://127.0.0.1/alpha/code/123` and I expect to receive `{"code": 123} status 200` but I don't know how to setup kong.yaml file to do this. If I send a request to `http://127.0.0.1/alpha/code/123` I get 404 from (from the alpha django application) which means kong is routing the request to alpha service but if I send a request to `http://127.0.0.1/alpha/code/abc` I get `{"message": "no Route matched with those values"}` which shows the regex is working

I could do this

```
services:
  - name: local-alpha-health
    url: http://host.docker.internal:9000/
    routes:
      - name: local-alpha-health
        methods:
          - GET
        paths:
          - /alpha
        strip_path: true
```

Then a request sent to `http://127.0.0.1/alpha/code/123` would go to ``http://127.0.0.1:9000/code/123` but I cannot control with regex

Any idea **How to route requests to a dynamic endpoint on kong api-gateway?**

This content seems related but cannot figure it out how to set it up
https://docs.konghq.com/gateway-oss/2.5.x/proxy/

Comment: Are you sure of the 1.1.X version ? this is a very old one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that a request like `http://127.0.0.1/alpha/code/abc` will indeed not match the rule you have added, because of the `\d+` (which matches one or more *digits*). Also, `http://127.0.0.1/alpha/code/123` will reach the upstream as a request to `/`, since you have `strip_path` set to true.

I have tested your example with some minor tweaks to proxy to a local httpbin service, which has a similar endpoint (`/status/<code>`).

Start a local httpbin service:

```
$ docker run --rm -d -p "8080:80" kennethreitz/httpbin
```

Start Kong with the following config:

```
_format_version: "2.1"

services:
  - name: local-alpha-code
    url: http://localhost:8080
    routes:
      - name: local-mockbin-status
        methods:
          - GET
        paths:
          - /status/(?<appcode>\d+)
        strip_path: false
```

Note that `strip_path` is set to `false`, so the entire matching path is proxied to the upstream.

Test it out with:

```
$ http :8000/status/200                                       
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
```

Comment: are you sure about this: `Also, http://127.0.0.1/alpha/code/123 will reach the upstream as a request to /, since you have strip_path set to true.`

I think it will reach upstream as request to `/code` because my url is `http://host.docker.internal:9000/code/`